# Displaying images from mysql via Jquery ?

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, image

Well, here it goes !
I am getting an array of images through get request from mysql database ! and displaying it as a slideshow. its working ! but what i am trying to do now is, display same images with Jquery.

```
    <?php require("Connections/db_con.php"); ?>
    <?php
    $title = "slideshow";
    $id = mysql_real_escape_string((int)$_GET['id']);
    $query_pic = "SELECT * FROM photos WHERE listing_id = $id ";
    $result_pic = mysql_query($query_pic , $db_con);
    $num_pic = mysql_num_rows($result_pic);
    $row_pic = mysql_fetch_array($result_pic);


    if($num_pic != 0) { 
        $image_set = array();
        $result = mysql_query("SELECT name FROM photos WHERE listing_id= $id");
        while($images = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
            array_push($image_set, $images['name']);
        }
    }
    ?>

    <html>
    <head>
    <title><>php echo $title; ?></title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheets/styles/styles.css" media='all'/>
    <link href="stylesheets/layout.css" media="all"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheets/styles/slideshow.css" media='all'/>
    <script type='text/javascript'>

    var photos  = new Array(<?php echo "'".implode("','", $image_set)."'"; ?>);
    var start   = 0; // array index of first slide
    var end     = <?php echo $num_pic -1; ?>; // array index of last slide
    var current = start;
    var doplay  = true; // do not play show automatically
    // skip to first slide
    function first() {
        current = 0;
        change();
    }

    // advance to next slide
    function previous() {
        current -= 1;
        if(current < start) current = end; // skip to last slide
        change();
    }

    // go back to previous slide
    function next() {
        current += 1;
        if(current > end) current = start; // skip to first slide
        change();
    }

    // skip to last slide
    function last() {
        current = end;
        change();
    }

    // change slide according to value of current
    function change() {
        document.photo.src = 'uploads/' + photos[current];
    }

    // play automatic slideshow
    function play() {
        if(doplay == true) {
            next();
            setTimeout(play, 2000); // call play() in 2.5 seconds
        }
    }

    // pause slideshow
    function pause() {
        doplay = false;
    }

    </script>
    </head>

    <body>

    <div id='container'>


    <div class='form'>

        <div id='photobox'>

            <img name='photo' src='uploads/<?php echo $image_set[0]; ?>' alt=''/><br /><br />
            <?php // echo "Total " . $num_pic . " photo(s) found" ; ?>

        </div>


    </div>

    </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

How can i display the same retrieved images with jquery slideshows rather than the one i am displaying it right now ?.. i tried hard but i fail everytime .. :(

Comment: where's the bit about jquery? we need to know what goes wrong on that code.

Comment: there is a `cycle plugin for jquery` for slide shows google for it

Answer (score 1):

This:

```
var photos  = new Array(<?php echo "'".implode("','", $image_set)."'"; ?>);
```

should be

```
var photos = <?php echo json_encode($image_set) ?>;
```

json_encode will take care of all the formatting/escaping of the PHP array into equivalent Javascript syntax, without the danger of any JS metacharacters in one-or-more of the filenames causing a JS syntax error.

Beyond that, exactly what is the problem with jquery? You should show your jquery code, since that's where the problem is. Showing us the old code is pointless.